# Do I realy need to list @Entity twice?

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to create a simple Hibernate (version 5.4) application with `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. I'm using `SessionFactory`.
All the entities are annotated with `@Entity`. To my surprise, the application doesn't work without  `<mapping class="..."/>` tags as well. No autodetaction works.
So I have to list entities twice - with the `@Entity` annotation in code and within the `mapping` tag in XML file. Is that correct?

Comment: Is it java ee application? Do you use application server?

Comment: No, it' Java SE application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize the hibernate's `SessionFactory` in the following way:

```java
MetadataSources metadata = new MetadataSources(
   new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build()
);

for (Class<?> clazz: ClassUtil.getClassesForPackage("com.xxx.hibernate.entities"))
{
   if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class)) {
      metadata.addAnnotatedClass(clazz);
   }
}

Metadata meta = metadata.buildMetadata();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = meta.buildSessionFactory();
```

Where the `ClassUtil.getClassesForPackage` method uses one of approaches described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection).